# I keep getting Bad Request when i try to access HttpPost Web Api method

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-webapi

I keep getting Bad Request when I try to access HttpPost Web Api method. I tried to check if any field is missing between the angular model and webapi model but nothing changed.

Also tried to debug the api, the issue occurs when the input model is created in 'constructor' function. and the api method never called.

what do you suggest? Please

````
saveComplaint() {
    const formModel = this.form.value;

    let newComplaint: ComplaintPostModel = {
      Id: 0,
      CustomerID: formModel.customerID,
      ComplaintSourceID: formModel.complaintSourceID,
      ComplaintTypeID: formModel.complaintTypeID,
      ComplaintStatusID: formModel.complaintStatusID,

      ComplainantOrganizationNameAmh: formModel.complainantOrganizationNameAmh,
      ComplainantPersonFullnameAmh: formModel.complainantPersonFullnameAmh,
      ComplainantOrganizationName: formModel.complainantOrganizationName,
      ComplainantPersonFullname: formModel.complainantPersonFullname,
      ComplaintRecievedBy: 1,
      DecisionDate: formModel.decisionDate,
      DecisionBy: 1,
      Description: formModel.description,

      ComplainantRegionID: formModel.complainantRegionID,
      ComplainantZoneID: formModel.complainantZoneID,
      ComplainantWeredaID: formModel.complainantWeredaID,
      ComplainantKebeleID: formModel.complainantKebeleID,
      ComplainantHouseNo: formModel.complainantHouseNo,
      ComplainantMobilePhone: formModel.complainantMobilePhone,
      ComplainantRegularPhone: formModel.complainantRegularPhone,

      IsActive: true,
      IsDeleted: false,
      CreatedDateTime: null,
      CreatedUserId: null,
      UpdatedDateTime: null,
      UpdatedUserId: null
    };

    console.log(newComplaint);
    this.lawEnforcementService.saveComplaint(newComplaint).subscribe(
      result => {
        this.router.navigate(['../complaint-list'], {});
      },
      error => {
      }
    );
  }

saveComplaint(complaint: ComplaintPostModel): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient
      .post<ComplaintPostModel>(`${applicationApis.complaintUrl}Save`, complaint, this.httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        map(data => {
          return data;
        })
      );
  }
``` TypeScript

zone.js:3243 POST http://localhost:60330/api/Complaint/Save 400 (Bad Request)
````

Comment: `Status code 400` means you're sending wrong keys in your payload. Once confirm with your `back-end` team whether you're sending correct keys in your payload

Comment: Sure would be helpful if we could see the actual server side code that's actually returning the 400. How can we be expected to help you figure out why this is happening, when we can't see the most important part?

Answer (score 0):

Got it working now. i added 'new Date(formModel.decisionDate)' for formModel.decisionDate and similarly for all date fields